# Suppose $\hat F_n(y)\overset{p}\to F(y)$, can we obtain $\sup_y|\hat F_n(y)-F(y)|\overset{p}\to0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

If we have

(i) $\hat F_n(y)\overset{p}\to F(y)$;

(ii) $|F(y)|\le1$;

(iii) $F(y)$ is a monotonically increasing function with respect to $y$.

Can we obtain the following result directly
$$\sup_y|\hat F_n(y)-F(y)|\overset{p}\to0?$$

Comment: Who is $\hat F$ here? Convergence (in probability, presumably) only makes sense with respect to a sequence.

Comment: Yes, it should have a subscript.

Comment: This is not true unless you add more conditions. Suppose all functions have their domain on $[0,1]$. Let 

$$F(y) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if } y=1\\
0 &\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Let $\hat{F}_n(y) = y^n$. Then $\hat{F}_n(y)$ converges to $F(y)$ for every $y$. This convergence happens in probability trivially (since it's a deterministic sequence), but,

$$\sup_y|\hat{F}_n(y) - F(y)| = 1 \text{ for all }n.$$